# Synchronized Methods in Java IO Streams

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

In Java since Java 1.0 in class `java.io.InputStream` there are methods

```
public synchronized void mark(int readlimit) {}
```

and

```
public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException("mark/reset not supported");
}
```

Why are those two methods synchronized while all the others are not?

Comment: There is no practical reason for them to be synchronized, maybe it's just a hint for `InputStream` subclass authors. Furthermore, it's very hard to imagine a realistic scenario when sharing a stream between two or more threads would be useful at all. (In fact it's hard to imagine a scenario where it wouldn't lead to disaster.)

Comment: @biziclop, I'm of the same opinion. It looks like mistake or rudiment. I just want to hear other opinions. Thanks!

Comment: Uh oh, now I have looked into the source code… Unnecessary synchronization is not as bad as the fact that the base implementation of `read(byte[],int,int)` swallows `IOException`s…

Comment: @Holger The implementation of `skip()` is quite peculiar too. And the fact that `InputStream` isn't an interface in the first place, given the uselessness of the skeleton implementations provided.

Comment: I’m also impressed by the code of `BufferedInputStream`. It eventually declares all `read` methods, `skip`, `mark` and `reset` as `synchronized`, ensuring indeed a consistent thread-safe behavior across all these operations. Then it provides an optimized `close` operation using CAS. I’m wondering what the authors think how often a stream gets closed, typically, compared to all the other operations named above…

Comment: If you give a test to `OutputStreamWriter`, you'll be impressed by performance as well. It works slow like a hell and sources are not available.

Comment: @Holger The re-implementation of `close()` could be the result of some kind of mass "clean-up" process when the `Closeable` interface was introduced.

Comment: @biziclop: indeed, both, the `Closeable` interface and the `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` were introduced with Java 5. Still, that “cleanup” looks more like an unnecessary complication. Ironically, `FileInputStream.close` uses `synchronized`…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few contradictory facts pointing that synchronized keyword is just a mistake here:

1. For sure it is just a hint for developers. Methods are empty and `synchronized` keyword is not inherited in subclasses.
2. On the other hand, other methods are not synchronized, even abstract and empty methods. That means we were warned not to forget about synchronization on mark/reset, but we were not warned about concurrent `read()` calls. That does not make sense because concurrent read will not work without synchronization.
3. Many of the JDK stream implementations have incoherent usage of synchronized keywords.
4. `java.io.InputStream` being put opposite to `java.nio.Buffer` has almost no useful basic method implementations but was made a class. So it tries to balance between this 'skeleton providing' and declaring general method contracts.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the reason, that mark() and reset() work together as you can see in the documentation.

> ***public void mark(int readlimit):***
>   Marks the current position in this input stream. A subsequent call to the `reset` method repositions this stream at the last marked
>   position so that subsequent reads re-read the same bytes.

If you have multiple threads which share the same InputStream, it could lead to problems, if these two methods wouldn't be synchronized.

**Update to comment**

`java.io.InputStream` is an abstract class so I think that the synchronized is more for the classes that inherits InputStream as a hint. The methods `mark()` and `reset()` will only be used, if `markSupported()` returns true. And in the class `java.io.InputStream#markSupported()` returns false.

```
/**
 * Tests if this input stream supports the <code>mark</code> and
 * <code>reset</code> methods. Whether or not <code>mark</code> and
 * <code>reset</code> are supported is an invariant property of a
 * particular input stream instance. The <code>markSupported</code> method
 * of <code>InputStream</code> returns <code>false</code>.
 *
 * @return  <code>true</code> if this stream instance supports the mark
 *          and reset methods; <code>false</code> otherwise.
 * @see     java.io.InputStream#mark(int)
 * @see     java.io.InputStream#reset()
 */
public boolean markSupported() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What kind of problem could happen to an empty method body?

Comment: As for me, it looks like a correct answer to a different question

Comment: @Antonio maybe I didn't get you right, my english isn't the best ;). Sorry for that, I hope an other person can help you.

Comment: the synchronized keyword isn't inherited by subclasses, how can it do any good for the classes that inherit from InputStream?

Comment: Even if you suppose that the `synchronized` modifier is just a *hint* for subclasses pointing to the need of synchronization, it would be inconsistent as the intended purpose of `mark()`/`reset()` implies that these operations must not interfere with the `read` operations as well. But the `read` methods are not `synchronized`…

Comment: Yeah you're right, silly me! I'm sorry for the wrong approach.

Answer (score -1):

Since mark() and reset() methods have no code inside them, the word "synchronized" is only a "reminder" to implementing classes that they should put locks on or in these methods when they override them.  This is to prevent race conditions on multi-threaded use-cases.

Now, other InputStream methods aren't marked as "synchronized" because these methods will never throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException, BufferOverflowException,etc. (unless you pass in bad buffer sizes).  These methods always return a -1 when there are no more bytes to read rather than throw an Exception.  So they don't need to be synchronized.

You'll notice that read() is abstract.  And implementing classes do specify "synchronized" when they implement this method.

In other words, abstract InputStream class can handle multi-threads and implementing classes should also.

Comment: The second paragraph is complete nonsense. Array index exceptions don't have anything do to with synchronization.

Comment: Huh?  In a multi-threaded environment when arrays are involved like it is in InputStream, you can get all sorts of exceptions if you don't put in the proper locks.